# Google Chrome doesn't render background-color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a custom bootstrap `navbar`, this is basically extending the functionality of the bootstrap `navbar`.

The following is an extract of the code from the `navbar` (I didn't paste all the code because it becomes quite long and the other code probably won't help resolve the issue. I can confirm that all the `div`'s and elements do get closed.)

```
echo "<div class='navbar navbar-app navbar-static-top'>";
    echo "<div class='navbar-header'>";
        echo "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-expand-menu'>";
            echo "<li>";
                echo "<a href='#' id='minimize-side-bar'>";
                    echo "<i class='fa fa-ellipsis-v'></i>";
                echo "</a>";
            echo "</li>";
        echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";
```

Basically what happens is when you click on the `minimize-side-bar` link and then click off the page (so that it keeps the state of the element as `:focus`) it doesn't keep the styling of the background color (see image below).

I have checked in chrome developer tools (DT) to see which CSS rule was overwriting the background color, but according to DT the rule was being applied.

Am I doing something wrong in my CSS or is this a chrome issue?

[image: From here you can see that developer tools shows the rule is active but does not render it]

Comment: Check the background value on the parent <li> or on the :before or :after element ;)

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your page using Ctrl + F5? Or wiping off the cache that may hold really tight on to some old styles? After you've opened the inspector, you can right-click the refresh button on your browser and force it to load the page all over.

Comment: @VincentG there are no styling rules for the `<li>` or the `<ul>` parents, that was one of the first things that I checked.

@ProDexorite I have cleared cache and refreshed both using the chrome settings and doing a hard reset while developer tools was open, I have also opened the stylesheet and hit Ctrl + F5 to ensure that the browser caches the latest version of the stylesheet.

Comment: Is this chrome 49 by some slight chance?

Comment: Do you have a link to check with chrome devTools ?

Comment: @Bálint haha why yes it is, is this a common issue with chrome (I didn't pick anything up while searching google)

Comment: @Pietro what do you mean by a link to check?

Comment: If you have a staging online site, I would like to browse with chrome devtools myself, and then write the answer if I can find the solution

Comment: I'm officially amazing. Have you tried in different browsers? Chrome 49 is very buggy.

Comment: Maybe an other element overlap the menu when :focus. Can you share a link so we can test to reproduce the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you found the issue, but just a small correction to what you said, which will help you understand it better :-)

Firstly, the `:hover` state on the element is not set by Google Chrome but the `bootstrap.min.css(line no.5)`. The browser merely just applies the rules set on the stylesheets. If you just click on the underlined `bootstrap.min.css:5`, you will be able to see where exactly is the value coming from.

Secondly most importantly, you don't necessarily need to give the `!important` parameter. If you want to override the style to your own style, all you need to do is mention the exact path of the selector to override it.

Instead of

```
.navbar-header li a:focus,
.navbar-header li a:active {
    background-color: #5ecdde !important;
}
```

In your `styles.css`, You need to give

```
.nav > li > a:focus,
.nav > li > a:active {
    background-color: #5ecdde;
}
```

**Basically use the same path followed (`.nav > li > a`) in bootstrap.min.css(blue hightlighted box), to override the styles.**

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue,

If you look at the image I posted in the question, I noticed that its overriding the color from the native bootstrap CSS. So I decided to change my CSS to this:

```
.navbar-header li a:focus,
.navbar-header li a:active,
.navbar-header li a:hover{
    background-color: #5ecdde !important;
}
```

What I think happened was the google chrome kept a `:hover` state on the element even if the cursor wasn't over the element. This seems to have solved the issue.

[image]